# Compare between two bash arrays inside docker

Tags: bash, docker

I need two make a new bash array, not including elements which are in second one. And then use this array in while loop:

```
while [ -n "${ids_toproc[0]}" ] ; do
```

Here is a code a implemented:

```
all_ids=( /input/sub-* )
all_ids=( "${all_ids[@]#/input/sub-}" )
all_ids=( "${all_ids[@]%/}" )

exist_ids=( /output/fmriprep/sub-*.html )
exist_ids=( "${exist_ids[@]#/output/fmriprep/sub-}" )
exist_ids=( "${exist_ids[@]%/}" )
exist_ids=( "${exist_ids[@]%%.*}" ) # delete extention

ids_toproc=( `echo ${all_ids[@]} ${exist_ids[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -u` )
```

Is code is ok? is it right way to do compare?

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow-up question to "[shell script inside docker](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/504349/shell-script-inside-docker)". Thanks for posting it as a separate issue!

What I would probably have done here, since the creation of your `all_ids` array needs to be slightly more complicated than just parsing the ID out from directory names, is to use a loop in which each ID is checked against the filenames the `/output/fmriprep` directory.  If no output file is found for a given ID, *then* the ID is added to the `all_ids` list.

```
all_ids=()
for dirname in /input/sub-*/; do
    id=${dirname#/input/sub-}    # remove "/input/sub-"
    id=${id%/}                   # remove trailing "/"

    if [ ! -e "/output/fmriprep/sub-$id.html" ]; then
        # no output file corresponding to this ID found,
        # add it to he list
        all_ids+=( "$id" )
    fi
done
```